# My application name changes after runtime, but it has no file extension, I want it to be in .exe

Tags: c++

My application name changes after runtime, but it has no file extension. I want it to be an .exe.
I'm new to c++ and I really need to figure this out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

std::string path()
{
    char shitter[_MAX_PATH]; // defining the path
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, shitter, _MAX_PATH); // getting the path
    return std::string(shitter); //returning the path
}

 
int main()
{    
    srand(time(NULL));
    char letter = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
    const char *val = new char(letter);
        std::rename(path().c_str(), val); //renaming the file

}
```

I tried doing this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

std::string path()
{
    char shitter[_MAX_PATH]; // defining the path
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, shitter, _MAX_PATH); // getting the path
    return std::string(shitter); //returning the path
}

int main() {
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS); // Higher Priority
    SetConsole();
    srand(time(NULL));
    char letters = 'A'+ (rand() % 26);
    const char* val = new char(letters);
    std::string rename(path().c_str(), val += ".exe"); //renaming the file
```

But now im getting an error

https://prnt.sc/uejlxz

Answer (score 0):

```c
rename(path().c_str(), val + ".exe")
```

or use append

[String Concatenation](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_strings_concat.asp)

Comment: Adding `char*`s together doesn't cause string concatenation in C++.